# Cannot connect to mongodb from another pod in kubernetes cluster

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes

There is a running a kubernetes cluster with a Web server, a Redis server, and a MongoDB server which is using official docker image: *`mongo:4.4.0`*

I exposed MongoDB server with name `mongodb` and Redis server with name `redis`:

```sh
NAME      TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)     AGE
backend   ClusterIP   172.19.14.124   <none>        7001/TCP    15h
mongodb   ClusterIP   172.19.10.24    <none>        27017/TCP   15h
redis     ClusterIP   172.19.6.203    <none>        6379/TCP    15h
```

Now, from backend webserver, I cannot connect to MongoDB server with `mongo --host mongodb` but connect to Redis using `redis -h redis` works.

Then checked by *`kubectl exec -it mongodb-5f4bd8c8d-hbsfx -- bash`*:

1. `mongo mongodb` works, it connected to `127.0.0.1`
2. `mongo 172.19.10.24` fail,  it results in
   `Error: couldn't connect to server 172.19.10.24:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 172.19.10.24:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :`
3. `ping mongodb` works well.

From the `ps` result, it already bind all:

`mongodb      1  0.2  2.5 1588248 98272 ?       Ssl  Aug20   2:02 mongod --bind_ip_all`

What's wrong and how to fix it? thx.

---

### update

command `ss` result from pod

```
LISTEN     0        0                  0.0.0.0:27017            0.0.0.0:*        users:(("mongod",pid=1,fd=9))
```

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: tabby
  name: mongodb
  labels:
    app: mongodb
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 27017
    targetPort: 27017
  selector:
    name: mongodb
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: tabby
  name: mongodb
  labels:
    app: mongodb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongodb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongodb
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred
      containers:
      - name: mongodb
        image: mongo:4.4.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /data/db
      volumes:
      - name: data
        emptyDir: {}
```

Comment: Is it a brand new cluster? you have any other network policies configured?

Comment: Maybe mongodb is listening on localhost:27017 only?

Comment: it's a new cluster, no network policies configured.

Comment: Burak Serdar might be correct. Also, this is likely to happen if the targetPort is misconfigured. Can we have a look at your MongoDB service YAML.

Comment: append yaml & ss result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service selector has `name: mongodb` but deployment has got `app: mongodb` label.  Because of this mismatch service is not selecting the pods. If you check the `Endpoints` section of the service using `kubectl describe svc mongodb -n tabby` you will not see any Pod IPs because of the above reason.

Change the service as follows.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: tabby
  name: mongodb
  labels:
    app: mongodb
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 27017
    targetPort: 27017
  selector:
    app: mongodb
```